# App looks like master-detail acts like tabbar controller

Tags: ios, ipad, uitabbarcontroller, master-detail

I need to develop something looks like master-detail ipad app but needs to act like tab bar app.

To make it more clear I will try to explain  with below example.

```
Master View        Detail View Controller
   ||                       ||
Section A   -------Navigation Controller
Section B   -------Navigation Controller
Section C   -------Navigation Controller
```

I was thinking how to do that and found this app does exactly what I want.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Above app acts like what I exactly want. Now difference from a regular `master detail split view controller` is, in master detail you would have one `detail root` and need to navigate from there.

Somehow above app accomplished each item on `masterview` has its own navigation controller and when you choose an item on `masterview` and come back to your old selection view stays on stack.  (Like Facebook App but better).

Lets say your on

```
(Master)      (Detail)
Section A     Navigation Root ---->VC1--->VC2--->VC3
```

If you choose another section on master

```
(Master)      (Detail)
Section b     Navigation Root ---->VC1
```

When you navigate `between master sectionA` and `master sectionB` ,you find your views on the same position on the stack. So when you go back to `Section A` you will see VC3.

My client wants the same feature in an app.
Do you guys have any ideas,resources about the logic behind above functionality?

Thanks,
S

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make the detail view controller be a tab bar controller with the tab bar hidden. Selecting an item in the master table would then just be setting the selectedIndex property of the tab bar controller.

Comment: ok make sense, do you think apple will be ok with it? I mean when I submit the app to appstore

Comment: @SpaceDust, yeah, it's definitely OK to put it in a split view controller. Apple even mentions that in the tab bar controller documents (in the View Controller Catalog for iOS).

Comment: ok, could you also look at this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15440502/created-tabbarcontroller-in-storyboard-cant-change-view-programmatically/15449219#15449219