# Created TabbarController in Storyboard can't change view programmatically

Tags: ios, objective-c, ipad, uitabbarcontroller

Created a `tabbarcontroller` as a detail view of splitview controller. I can change the view by clicking `item1`, `item2` icons on simulator, but can not change view programmatically.

I am getting `null`  when try to print `viewcontrollers` in `nslog` .
In MasterView:

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) TabBarRootViewController *detailViewController;
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    self.detailViewController=[[TabBarRootViewController alloc] init];
//tried also
self.detailViewController = (TabBarRootViewController *)[self.splitViewController.viewControllers objectAtIndex:1];

}
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    //this sends object info to detail
    if (indexPath.section==0) {
        //send row number
       NSNumber *i = [NSNumber numberWithInteger:indexPath.row];
        NSLog(@"Selected index %@",i);

        self.detailViewController.detailItem = i;
    }
}
```

In detail(Tabbar):

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) id detailItem;

if (self.detailItem) {
    NSInteger i=[self.detailItem integerValue];
    NSLog(@"recieved integer is %i",i);

    //tried this
    self.tabBarController.selectedIndex=i;
    self.tabBarController.selectedViewController = [self.tabBarController.viewControllers objectAtIndex:i];

    //list of viewcontrollers
    NSArray *array;
    array = [[self tabBarController] viewControllers];
    NSLog(@"array %@",array);

}
```

[image]

```
NSLOG:
recieved integer is 1
array (null)
```

How can I change the view programmatically?

Thanks,

S

Comment: Why do you have the tab bar controller in a navigation controller? What controller is the above code in?

Comment: @rdelmar without navigation controller I get `[TabbarRootViewController topViewController]: unrecognized selector sent to instance` error . The code is in `TabbarRootViewController`

Comment: Then don't call topViewController! I see no reason for you to have a navigation controller there. Are you pushing to anything? If not, get rid of it. And what is all that about the moreNavigationController? That's only present if you have more than 5 tabs.

Comment: @rdelmar ok removed the `navigation controller` and `topviewcontroller` requests but still getting `null` in nslog. In masterview `viewdidload` I call  `self.detailViewController=[[TabBarRootViewController alloc] init];` and when a row selected I want to change the  tabbar item to selected row index. Updated the question added where I call the tabbardetail item in masterview

Comment: I can't read the names of the controllers on the image you posted, so it's hard to tell what controllers you're talking about. However, if TabBarRootViewController is one of the controllers in your storyboard, you shouldn't be alloc init'ing it. From what I can see, that's the detail view controller of the split view controller, so it can be referenced with self.splitViewController.viewControllers[1]  (the one at index 0 would be the master controller). You really need to read the 2 docs linked at the top of the UIViewController Class Reference to understand what you're supposed to do.

Comment: just solved the problem, I know I should not alloc init it but I tried lots of stupid things but finally figured it out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was not able to get the exact pointer to theTabbarcontroller.

I removed the navigation controller and left only tabbar controller.Also removed the `[topcontroller]` requests in master view and appdelegate.

So final working code is

appdelegate:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    // Override point for customization after application launch.
    return YES;
}
```

masterview:
- (void)viewDidLoad

```
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    self.detailViewController = (TabBarRootViewController *)[self.splitViewController.viewControllers objectAtIndex:1];

}
```

in tabbarcontroller (detail controller)

```
@property (strong,nonatomic) UITabBarController *rootController;

        self.rootController= (TabBarRootViewController *)[self.splitViewController.viewControllers objectAtIndex:1];
        self.rootController.selectedIndex=i;
```

Comment: So I was right - it *was* nil. You should leave your answer for reference but award the correct answer to me.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like your tab bar controller is `nil`.  Maybe not correctly linked with storyboard?

Comment: no, I can choose `(TabBarRootViewController *)[self.splitViewController.viewControllers objectAtIndex:1];` and I have checked class name on storyboard which is right.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `performSegueWithIdentifier:sender:` on your current controller.

This is because your controller is now controlled by the storyboard and it must maintain state etc.

Note that you need to give your segues an ID in the storyboard editor and you cannot use your own inits, instead you have to override `prepareForSegue:sender:` to inject properties.

Good luck.

Comment: Actually, you can override `initWithCoder` if you need.

Comment: Yes, but that promotes coupling

Comment: I don't think it does. View controllers and their corresponding objects in xib or storyboard files are *already coupled*.

Comment: I was attempting to allude to the fact that this method provides an entry point for injection. Furthermore it is apples prefered way of navigating when using storyboard.